# How to Increase Scrollbar Width in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-12.10

I'm trying to figure out a hack that will allow me to increase the default scroll-bar-width in Ubuntu for Firefox and numerous other applications:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1078681

  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1077559

  http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/29104/

Any suggestions?

Comment: I found this, and was able to increase the width of scrollbars:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/94147/how-do-i-make-the-scrollbars-wider

Comment: Not sure why the accepted answer was accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have overlay scrollbars, I'm not sure if it's possible to make them wider. You can, however, disable them very easily, with following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface ubuntu-overlay-scrollbars false
```

If you have default scrollbars,  their width is controlled by the theme you're using.